# Why my SQL query doesnt work in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, google-maps, point, geography

So I use ms sql to store latitude and longitude in geography point, in sql I acces that data with:

```
  SELECT
  location.Lat AS  lat,
  location.long AS long,
  location
  FROM tableName;
```

And it work good, lat is 20,4706622 long is 44,8132969 and location is some messy hexa number.

But when I try same in PHP it doesnt work, it's same and is caused by:

```
location.lat/long
```

Here is how my php looks like

```
<?php 
session_start();

include "connect.php";

$query = $handler->query("SELECT location.lat AS lat, street  FROM shops");
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$location[0] = $row->lat;
$location[1] = $row->street;
echo json_encode($location);
```

If I replace location.lat/long with anything else like location, street, city or any other column it will work.
I know it is up to location.lat, but I do not know how to format it different.
If anything is not clear please ask.

Comment: could you rename your fields and remove `location.` Sql recognizes this as you want to use the field `lat` from the location table

Comment: location is some hexadecimal number, location.lat converts it to number that I need? What fields you want me to rename?

Comment: I also wonder where you got the field `street` from. I looks like your using more then 1 table or you just magically added streets to your table. Could you add all required info (tables your are using)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5cc4cdf3-d882-4342-9ff4-525e17fd8a3f/how-to-get-latlong-from-geography-data-type?forum=sqlspatial no location.lat is just some derived data from location in sql, its not new column or table, its all from same table. Check this out also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx when you add SET @g = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326) into table it turns location field to something like this: 0xE6100000010CD7A3703D0AD728C09A99999999B94340 which can be converted with location.lat to 47.65100.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you named your fields `location.Lat` and `location.long`

Change your field names of your table to `lat` and `long`

Then change your query to:

```
SELECT
  Lat AS  lat,
  long AS long,
  location
  FROM tableName;
```

---

Another option is to create a view if you can't change the db structure for some reason.

According to you this query works:

```
SELECT
  location.Lat AS  lat,
  location.long AS long,
  location
  FROM tableName;
```

If your query works then you could create a view by:

```
create view new_table_name as 
SELECT location.Lat AS  lat, location.long AS long, location FROM tableName;
```

Then change your php script to use the new view as if it was a normal table.

```
Select * from new_table_name
```

Should give you an idea what just happened.

Comment: No, I didnt name columnlocation.lat and location.long, name of the column is location and location only, and you need to type location.lat and location.long to extract that data from locations.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5cc4cdf3-d882-4342-9ff4-525e17fd8a3f/how-to-get-latlong-from-geography-data-type?forum=sqlspatial no location.lat is just some derived data from location in sql, its not new column or table, its all from same table. Check this out also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx when you add SET @g = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326) into table it turns location field to something like this: 0xE6100000010CD7A3703D0AD728C09A99999999B94340 which can be converted with location.lat to 47.65100.

Comment: then location is a microsoft sql server `function` which php doesn't know. Try my second option. Create a view and use that view in your php script as a table